# Why was the diaeresis removed from Pasiphae?

Tags: natural-satellites, history, naming, nomenclature

The [Gazetteer of Planetary Nomenclature](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Page/Planets#JovianSystem) notes that the spelling of Jupiter's moon Pasiphae was changed from Pasiphaë in July 2009, i.e. they removed the diaeresis. I've been unable to track down the rationale for this decision. Is anyone aware of why the spelling was changed?

Comment: The name wasn’t changed, just the orthography. The use of diacritics has been diminishing for many decades: you rarely see “coöperation” any more, and even “naïve” is often written with a plain “i”. Is Boötes still the formal spelling?

Comment: Note that in the 1975 minutes no dieresis is used, but this may just be an artifact of the technological limitations of the time https://www.iau.org/static/administration/ecminutes/ec40minutes.pdf  (page7

Comment: However note that in the report https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nv7nCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA337&dq=planetary%20system%20nomenclature%20pasiphae&pg=PA337#v=onepage&q&f=false The dieresis is absent,  but the umlaut on Dr Jürgen Blunk's name is written.  This is almost an answer  "The diaresis was never part of the name, and was only used hypercorrectly"  Probably a report in 2009 clarified that.